# Configure UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching range

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to configure `UICollectionView`, so that `prefetchDataSource` will preload more items? I would like to specify the exact preloading range.

By default,  [`UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching) is called to prefetch a number of items enough to cover a half of the screen, and when the user scrolls further it can preload up to the entire screen of items.

Comment: Kelin I don't think it possible to do in frontend. In my app we pass a constant (ex number of items to prefetch) and my API return the exact number of items

Answer (score 1):

There is no public api to manage prefetched items count directly.

Prefetching is based on visible area of the collection view. Yet you have [collectionView(_:cancelPrefetchingForItemsAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/1771769-collectionview) delegate method, where you can cancel or reduce the priority of prefetched item based on it's `indexPath`

This [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/) (35 min long) has all the explanations needed. (sorry for the "link" answer, but I believe WWDC is a reliable source of information).

Comment: I'm looking for undocumented ways to implement this. Like private API, hack or a beautiful workaround.